# Elements refuse to move - jQuery .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have an odd problem. I'm building a simple helicopter game (the old type - click to go up, avoid obstacles). My problem is that the obstacles generate, but don't position correctly, and then they won't move. I'm trying to move them with jQuery's `css()` - the `css` method works fine on anything else but when used with `top` and `left` doesn't.

The problem functions (generate and move obstacles):

```
game.background.generateObs = function() {
var top = Math.floor(Math.random()*game.canvas.height);
var left = game.canvas.width-10;
var $obs = $("<div></div>")
$obs.addClass("obs").appendTo("#canvas");
$obs.css({
    background: "black",
    position: "absolute",
    height: game.obstacle.height,
    width: game.obstacle.width,
});
$obs.css("top", $("#canvas").offset().top  + top )
    .css("left",$("#canvas").offset().left + left);
game.obstacle.width = Math.floor(Math.random()*200);
if(game.gameState=="running") {
    setTimeout("game.background.generateObs()",obsInterval);
}
else {
    return;
}
}

game.background.moveObs = function() {
var currentPos = $("#canvas div.obs").css("left");
var newPos = currentPos - game.obstacle.frameWidth;
$("#canvas div.obs").css("left",newPos);
if(game.gameState=="running") {
    setTimeout("game.background.moveObs()",interval);
}
else {
    return;
}
}
```

The other thing is that jsFiddle is now telling me that `game` is undefined, when I have defined it right at the start.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nf4n3/).

Comment: To make your variables global (so `game` is defined), change the second dropdown on the left from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Nf4n3/1/

Comment: I would put all your functions inside the global game variable and use a method invocation pattern, that might help fix things and improve readibility of your code.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Thanks - but the obstacles still refuse to move

Comment: Try changing `setTimeout("game.background.generateObs()",obsInterval);` to `setTimeout(game.background.generateObs,obsInterval);`

Comment: I played a bit with your code, check an updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Nf4n3/4/

Comment: What do you expect `$("#canvas div.obs").css("left")` to return? It evaluates as "auto" for me. Try using `.offset().left` instead, perhaps.

Comment: @Blazemonger: The current `left` value of `#canvas div.obs`. Let me try...

Comment: Thanks to all - appears to be working. @alou: the edit helped a lot.

Comment: @Blazemonger: that was just the solution I wanted. If you care to post it as an answer I'll UV and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#canvas div.obs").css("left")` is returning `auto` in your fiddle, not a number.

Try using .offset().left instead.

---

Additionally, you should change your `setTimeout` calls like this:

```
setTimeout(game.background.moveObs,interval);
```